# Facebook FQL query for fetching news feeds does not work all the times

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

Hi i wrote a FQL query to fetch the news feeds which returns the results sometimes and  returns empty result set most of the times.The weird part is the same query returns a proper result set while executing from Facebook Graph API Explorer tool.
I don't understand why exactly the issue is happening leaving me without any clue.
Here is the query what i am using

```
SELECT actor_id, app_id, attachment, attribution, comment_info, created_time, description, description_tags, likes, message, message_tags, place, post_id, share_count, source_id, tagged_ids, target_id, type, via_id, with_location, with_tags FROM stream WHERE (source_id = me() OR source_id IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()) ) AND (place OR type <> 237) ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 300
```

Comment: So you're using this with a v2.0 app?

Comment: FQL is deprecated, you should not build anything based on it any more. Use the Graph API instead.

Comment: @ CBroe Yes i do know that they are deprecated, but i am using v2.0

Comment: Still makes little sense to start implementing something based on it now. // If you are getting different results in GAE and in your app, then first of all go check what permissions the access token (used in your app) actually contains.

Comment: It might also be the case that the access token for your own app does not have the same set of permission scopes as the token for the Graph API Explorer app that you are using, and that one scope is missing that would be required to get the data you're looking for.